# Get first frame of an flv video into a jpg image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, thumbnails, record

I am creating an app with flex for recording a video and i want to capture the first image of the video recorded, by now i use the following function in order to capture the 
first image but its rather slow

```
private function capture():void
{
 var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width, videoDisplay.height);
 bitmapData.draw(videoDisplay);

 var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
 var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);

 var base64_enc: Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
 base64_enc.encodeBytes(ba,0,ba.length);
 imgEncoded = base64_enc.toString();

}
```

and i would like to get the first frame of the recorded video as a thumb after it is recorded
is there any idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

LoaderMax videoloader does it for you, you can check out source codes.

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/